# Partitioning a progression

Tags: real-analysis, combinatorics, number-theory, arithmetic, additive-combinatorics

Let $P $ be a $Z_N $ progression of length $R $.Prove that we can partition  $P $ into at most $4 \sqrt R $ genuine arithmetic progressions. (Genuine arithmetic progression means arithmetic progression in $\mathbb {N} $).

In order to prove this I assume that the progression  $P $ is $a+ jq $ with  $1 \leq j \leq R$.
By Dirichlet's theorem, there exists  $l \leq \sqrt R , b\in \mathbb {N}$ such that  $|\frac { l}{N} - \frac {b}{q}|\leq \frac {R^{-\frac { 1}{2}} } {q}$.we can divide $P $ into sub-progressions of  $j $ ( mod $l $ ).

How can I continue?

Is there any hint how to prove the statement?

Thanks in advance.